# Why does the error “attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'” occur and how can I avoid it?

Tags: boot

I know how to solve the error but I would like to know why it occurs and how to avoid it in the future because my computer is getting the same error many times. I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: And what exactly are you doing to bring up this error? And it simple means you are trying to access a section of your disk that is beyond what your partition table knows!

Comment: I am not sure, but usually, while I am using my web navigator it happens that my computer suddenly turns off and when I turn on again the error message appears.

Comment: Perhaps you can run `fsck` on your HDD using a LiveUSB!

Comment: Ok, it's done. `fsck` did not find any problem. However, my laptop continues showing the error. BTW, my laptop seems to overheat, could it be the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest unmounting the partition and file system checking it with `fsck`